# undefined reference to `crypt' : apache2 manually install error on imx8mqevk

Tags: linux, makefile, apache2, imx8

I am using an iMX8MQ EVK board with Linux. I want to install the apache2 server and MySQL database from the source. Started installing apache2 using [this](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/07/install-apache-2-from-source-on-linux/)

Here is the Linux version:

```
root@imx8mqevk:~# cat /etc/os-release
ID=fsl-imx-wayland
NAME="NXP i.MX Release Distro"
VERSION="5.10-hardknott (hardknott)"
VERSION_ID=5.10-hardknott
PRETTY_NAME="NXP i.MX Release Distro 5.10-hardknott (hardknott)"
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/ayyEexYZ) is the output of configure

Facing issue with make as crypto is not found. I am not able to resolve the issue.
I have tried installing glibc but the issue is not resolved.
make error

```
Making all in support
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/root/httpd-2.4.53/support'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/root/httpd-2.4.53/support'
/usr/local/apr/build-1/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -pthread         -o htpasswd  htpasswd.lo passwd_common.lo       /usr/local/apr/lib/libaprutil-1.la -lexpat /usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-1.la -lrt -lpthread -ldl
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/10.2.0/../../../../aarch64-poky-linux/bin/ld: passwd_common.o: in function `mkhash':
/home/root/httpd-2.4.53/support/passwd_common.c:228: undefined reference to `crypt'
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/10.2.0/../../../../aarch64-poky-linux/bin/ld: /home/root/httpd-2.4.53/support/passwd_common.c:240: undefined reference to `crypt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:48: htpasswd] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/root/httpd-2.4.53/support'
make[1]: *** [/home/root/httpd-2.4.53/build/rules.mk:75: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/root/httpd-2.4.53/support'
make: *** [/home/root/httpd-2.4.53/build/rules.mk:75: all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: You should modify your build environment to explicitly link with libcrypto.so library (probably by adding a `-lcrypt` flag to the linker command).

Comment: Resolved with fresh image from NXP website which was having all the dependencied